# bundle gem jekyll-sitemap error incompatible character encodings

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, bundler

*Disclaimer: My first question on stackoverflow ...* so first off all "Hello world"

I'm having a bad time adding [jekyll-sitemap](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap/) plugin to my site.
This is my Gemfile:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
```

Running `bundle` results in:

```
Installing jekyll-sitemap 1.1.1
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
An error occurred while installing jekyll-sitemap (1.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install jekyll-sitemap -v '1.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm on Ubuntu btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of frustration I somehow solved it ... kinda ... I just took a different path:
first I `sudo apt purge ruby` and manually deleted all leftovers in `/usr/`, `/var/` and my `home` directory. Then I reinstalled `ruby` **and** `ruby-dev`

```
sudo apt install ruby ruby-dev
```

I abandoned the idea of using `bundler`. Instead I installed `jekyll-sitemap` like that:

```
sude gem install jekyll-sitemap
```

I had to install it with sudo because without there is an error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

### Configuring Jekyll

Jekyll's `_config.yml` file still needs the addition which is mentioned in the installation manual:

```
gems:
  - jekyll-sitemap
```

---

When I run `gulp` everything works as expected and the sitemap is generated.